# Adding Distance (KM and Miles) to a Map using ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, distance

Using ArcGIS 10.1, how do you add and show the distance in mile / km markings alongside the marked trails(KM and miles) while using the aforementioned 10.1?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to put Mile markers? Or put the total length of the Trail as a label?

Comment: Put Mile/KM markers along the trail and total distance calculated too (but, I can add that manually)

Answer (score 1):

There are many permutations for how you might like to label your line and these are all available from your **Layer Properties**.

However, to get the lengths available as populated fields in your line attribute table in both units, I would recommend using Add Field and then **[Calculate Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000)**.

Comment: I know how to calculate geometry to get the total distance, but am trying to get the distance such as "Mile markers) along the trails.

Comment: That would have been useful to illustrate on your map. For that Linear Referencing will be needed.